# Limit width in an excel file created by asp.net with multiple GridViews

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview

My asp.net page needs to download multiple grids to an excel file. The problem is that the width needs to be limited so that it should fit on one page. I can get it to work fine with one grid, but not with multiple grids. With multiple grids it ignores the “Wrap” & “Width” fields of the grid. The grids need to display on one worksheet

Ready to tear out my hair.  please help!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
  private BoundField CreateBoundField(String headerText, String dataField, int width)
    {
        BoundField bf = new BoundField();
        bf.HeaderText = headerText;
        bf.DataField = dataField;
        bf.ItemStyle.Wrap = true;
        bf.ItemStyle.Width = new Unit(width);
        bf.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
        bf.ItemStyle.VerticalAlign = VerticalAlign.Top;

        return bf;
    }


    private GridView CreateSystem1HwGridviewForExcel()
    {
        GridView gvSystem1HwExcel = new GridView();

        gvSystem1HwExcel.AutoGenerateColumns = false;




        gvSystem1HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Display Name", "DisplayName", 40));
        gvSystem1HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Item Name", "ItemName", 40));
        gvSystem1HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("HW Name", "HWName", 40));
        gvSystem1HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Item Type", "ItemType", 40));
        gvSystem1HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Manufacturer", "Manufacturer", 40));
        gvSystem1HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Model", "Model", 40));
        gvSystem1HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Serial Number", "SerialNumber", 40));
        gvSystem1HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Location", "Location", 40));
        gvSystem1HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Grid", "Grid", 40));
        gvSystem1HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("RU", "RU", 40));
        gvSystem1HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Hw Status", "HwStatus", 40));
        gvSystem1HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Power Status", "PowerStatus", 40));

        gvSystem1HwExcel.DataSource = dtSystem1Hardware;
        //gvSystem1HwExcel.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "gridHeader";

        gvSystem1HwExcel.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        gvSystem1HwExcel.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        gvSystem1HwExcel.DataBind();

        gvSystem1HwExcel.Style.Value = "word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word";
        gvSystem1HwExcel.Width = new Unit(10);

        return gvSystem1HwExcel;
    }

    private GridView CreateSystem2HwGridviewForExcel()
    {
        GridView gvSystem2HwExcel = new GridView();

        gvSystem2HwExcel.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

        gvSystem2HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Name", "Name", 40));
        gvSystem2HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Manufacturer", "Manufacturer", 40));
        gvSystem2HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Model", "Model", 40));
        gvSystem2HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Serial Number", "SerialNumber", 40));
        gvSystem2HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Location", "Location", 40));
        gvSystem2HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Grid", "Grid", 40));
        gvSystem2HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("HW Status", "HwStatus", 40));
        gvSystem2HwExcel.Columns.Add(CreateBoundField("Power Status", "PowerStatus", 40));


        gvSystem2HwExcel.DataSource = dtSystem2Hardware;
        //gvSystem2HwExcel.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "gridHeader";

        gvSystem2HwExcel.HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        gvSystem2HwExcel.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        gvSystem2HwExcel.DataBind();

        gvSystem2HwExcel.Style.Value = "word-break:break-all;word-wrap:break-word";
        gvSystem2HwExcel.Width = new Unit(10);

        return gvSystem2HwExcel;
    }

    protected void btnExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadUserInput();
        DisplayReport();

        string fileName = "attachment;filename= ArchivalReportOn_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") + ".xls";
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", fileName);
        Response.Buffer = false;  //sssssssssss
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "Application / vnd.xls";



        System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

       var gvSystem1HwExcel= CreateSystem1HwGridviewForExcel();
       gvSystem1HwExcel.RenderControl(htmlWrite);

       var gvSystem2HwExcel = CreateSystem2HwGridviewForExcel();
       gvSystem2HwExcel.RenderControl(htmlWrite);


        Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }

}
```